# ExceptionInInitializerError in org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity

Tags: android, multipartentity

I am trying to use the `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2` dependency on Android but get this exception:

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: SyncAdapterThread-1
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.<init>(MultipartEntity.java:71)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.<init>(MultipartEntity.java:91)`

when I call:

`MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();`

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this?

Comment: add your multipart code also

Comment: I should point out that my code was all working fine against the 4.2.6 JAR file. It only broke when I tried switching to the above Gradle dependency.

Comment: HTTP client has been removed in api 23 but you can still use it by adding  HTTP legacy in your gradle

Answer (score 0):

Apache HTTP has been [removed in Android M](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client). You shouldn't use it anymore.

I suggest you to use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) with MultipartBody or HttpURLConnection with DataOutputStream.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look, although this library was working fine when I had it referenced as a JAR rather than a Gradle dependency. I tried reversing my change but that didn't work...